# Enable user in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have disabled SA user and renamed it to 'sysadmin' but now i am seeing 'sysadmin' as disable user and want to enable it.I tried log in using windows authentication but not its giving me permission error while enabling 'sysadmin'.

Answer (score 5):

You can not enable or disable users, but can enable login related to that user.

```
Alter login sysadmin enable
```

Comment: nope...its giving me error "Cannot alter the login 'sysadmin', because you do not have permission."

Comment: You should be member of sysadmin or security admin to enable or disable a login. If you are not , so database engine is due to prevent you.

Comment: I got a solution....actually we should have windows user which have admin rights. Then with windows authentication we can login to database and enable SA user

Comment: You can do it with any account(windows account or sql server account) which has admin rights .